# Is it possible to unacknowledge messages in synchronous pull for pubsub

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am pulling pubsub messages through a subscription and need to acknowledge these before processing as I am doing multiprocessing and that throws an error of SSL corruption on account of the grpc module.

I want to ack all messages beforehand and unack in case there was an error, I am aware that we can do this for an asynchronous pull but is there a way where we can implement unack  in synchronous pull as well?

I am using the official python module to pull from subscription

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that `unack` you mean `nack` [explained](https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/subscriber/index.html#explaining-ack) in Python API reference:

> In Pub/Sub, the term **ack** stands for “acknowledge”.
>
> ...
>
> It is also possible to **nack** a message, which is the opposite...

The same documentation contain part [Pulling a Subscription Synchronously](https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/subscriber/index.html#pulling-a-subscription-synchronously)
 in which it is explained how to `nack` with `modify_ack_deadline()`:

> If you want to **nack** some of the received messages (...), you can use the **modify_ack_deadline()** method and set their
> acknowledge deadlines to zero. This will cause them to be dropped by
> this client and the backend will try to re-deliver them.